# What's the fastest way to load big image on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, performance, memory, uiimage

Should I use UIImage or CGImage ? Png or Jpg ?
I've read the doc and tried different things but did not notice significant improvement.
Loading an image can take 1 good second which seems slow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIImage` is just an ObjC wrapper of `CGImage`, so they're the same.

From the SDK doc:

> **You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x 1024 in size.** Besides the large amount of memory such an image would consume, you may run into problems when using the image as a texture in OpenGL ES or when drawing the image to a view or layer. This size restriction does not apply if you are performing code-based manipulations, such as resizing an image larger than 1024 x 1024 pixels by drawing it to a bitmap-backed graphics context. In fact, you may need to resize an image in this manner (or break it into several smaller images) in order to draw it to one of your views.

If you have a huge image, you could try to use a `UIWebView` to reduce memory consumption.

---

The time to load an image has 2 parts: the time to decompress the image (relevant to choosing JPG or PNG) and the time to render the image.

For decompressing, I'd suggest you profile the simple statement

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/your/image.jpg"];
```

Answer (score 4):

It is **faster for the iPhone to load PNGs than JPGs** because PNGs are optimized when bundled in your application (although, not loaded from remote).

An except from Addison Wesley's iPhone Cookbook:

*"Xcode automatically optimizes your PNG images using the pngcrush utility shipped with the SDK. (You'll find the program in the iPhoneOS platform folders in /Developer. Run it  from the command line with the –iphoneswitch to convert standard PNG files to iPhone- formatted ones.) For this reason, use PNG images in your iPhone apps where possible as your preferred image format."*

Also, **PNG is a lossless format**, and **JPGs are lossy**. Apple chose this format for these reasons.

-Kevin

Comment: Yes I knew about the png optimization from xcode but what about the case when you need to load png's from various sources (web, photo gallery). Then they are not optimized and this can be pretty slow :-/

Comment: That's mostly true that dynamically loaded (web, etc) photos are not optimized using Apple's tool. However, it's still the wisest choice, as your images will look flawless (and will still be quite small to conserve network bandwidth). In general, I've had much better luck with PNG than JPG.

Comment: I've benchmarked that and [Xcode images were **slower**](http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html) than standard PNG images optimized using other tools. File size (disk I/O?) was more important than byteswapping. I've only compared PNG to PNG, but I guess that a significantly smaller JPEG file would load quicker as well.

Comment: Really interesting. Thanks for pointing that out. I will have to keep that in mind.